# What can a king do to prevent Rudra from destroying his kingdom and people?

Tags: shiva, sin, kings, punishment, evil

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35744/11726) has shown that Rudra destroys evil countries.

My question is, what can a king do to prevent Rudra from destroying his kingdom and people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can a king do to prevent Rudra from destroying his kingdom and
>   people?

**By offering the [Ashvamedha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashvamedha).**

After the sacrificial horse has been slain in the year-long Ashvamedha ritual performed by the king, the king offers three libations of blood of the horse to Rudra to appease him so he doesn't harm the cattle and citizens of the king's country.

The *Taittiriya Brahmana* says,

> The king offers the third libation of blood of the slain sacrificial
>   horse by means of a bronze cup. The people certainly are of bronze,
>   and the Agni Svishtakrt is Rudra. He thus shields the people from
>   Rudra, and **in the country where this libation is offered, Rudra does
>   not attempt to injure the people.**